# When i install any flutter package, example projects are also including?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When i install any flutter package for eg: shared_preference, "example project" is also including along with that package for iOS, Android and Web. That increases my flutter project size. Initially my project size is in 1 mb or 2mb only. Including example projects also in package installation, my project size also increasing. Now my project size is 136mb.

How can i solve to reduce my project size?

Update :

I created new project.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC6UN.png)
Initial project size.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vhcg.png) After install shared_preference package.

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRfyB.png) After install pod for iOS.

Comment: what do you mean by >>0

When i install any flutter package for eg: shared_preference

is it on pubspec.yaml??

Comment: Wait..what..!?your project is initially 1mb or 2mb..how is it possible..

Comment: @srikanth7785 Yes. 
i am using flutter version : Flutter: 1.19.0-2.0.pre.143 with master channel. I created test project. Its just 349kb. If i install packages, increasing size.

Comment: Well, if you are talking about the directory size on your system..I would say that doesn't matter..I can say that you do not need to bother about that..just go with your work..app will have no effect with that..

Comment: Yes. Agree. But if i want to distribute source code, its hard to send even if i zipped it. Just looking for alternatives to reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the size of the final application it depends on the assets you have used in your application. If you want to reduce the size of the final application try to reduce the usage of local assets.

Comment: NO. App assets are very less. Total app size is 134mb. iOS folder is 97mb. Android folder is 35mb, remaining 2mb. 

ios folder ===> .symlinks/plugins===> shared_preference. Here android folder, ios folder and example folder.
i think for all packages, size is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command in the terminal

`flutter build apk`

And navigate to the folder

Your_Flutter_Application/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk

Try to install this apk in your device you can see the reduce in the size of the application

If you are talking about the space occupied by the project in you laptop/system it depends on the assets and the other dependences you use in the project we can't reduce it but the above procces will help you to reduce the final application size